# Folder structure in memory(compression and uncompression)

Tags: c#, stream, zip, byte

I need compress and uncompress strings only in memory, without saving it inside file.
It's easy to do that with one string but the problem appears when I need do this with many files. I don't want do compress every string creating array of bytes array.  Is it possible to compress many strings into one object (zip with many files in memory)and uncompress this dynamically ? (yield)

Also I have to deal with big strings(xml files) and I copy this data from procedure into MemotySream. I'd like to just compress data from this streams

Comment: put all the strings in an array, serialize the array and compress the result.

Comment: It's a good idea, but sorry I didn't specify my problem. Also i have to deal with big strings(xml files) and I copy this data from procedure into MemotySream. I'd like to just compress data from this streams.

Comment: Then it's even easier, create a GZipStream over an empty MemoryStream and a BinaryWriter over the GZipStream, write the content of the files you have in memory to the binary writer. To uncompress do the oposite, create a memorystream over the byte array, a gzip stream over the memorystream and a binary reader over the gzip stream.

Comment: Note that if you put everything in a single object, then you won't be able to access directly to a single element. You'll need to access it sequentially.

Comment: I'll leave that task for later, but it's sounds perfect and surely I'll try this.

Comment: Gusman, coultd you give a example how to resolve that? Should I in sequence write files to memory ?  How would I know how to unzip this bytes into many files?